# Go to div of another page in HTML

Tags: html

I would like to go to the DIV of a particular page from a different page. Is that possible?

I tried `<a href="file.html#product">Hello</a>`

but it just goes to `file.html#home`

thanks

C.

I have   in my file.html but it keeps getting redirected to file.html#home instead.

Comment: Please show the code of that `<div>`.

Comment: @KennyTM, i'm sure the content of the div is irrelevant.. C just want's to go there :)

Answer (score 8):

With HTML 5, you need to simply add an `id` attribute to your `<div>` with a value of `product`. This needs to be a unique `id` attribute within the page (for all elements):

```
<div id="product">
```

See the [working draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

In HTML 4.01 you need to use an anchor tag with a `name` just above your target div, or any other element with an `id` attribute in the other page:

```
<a name="product"></a>
<div>...
```

See the HTML 4.01 [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1).

**Note:** The `name` attribute has been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10) in the XHTML 1.0 spec.

So, this would be a better option, as it would work for HTML 4.01, XHTML 1.0 and HTML 5:

```
<div id="product">
```

Comment: For suggesting deprecated HTML.

Comment: @RoToRa - can you please point me to the source that shows this is deprecated?

Comment: @Oded: The attribute isn't even in the [HTML5 spec for <a>](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1#h-4.10. 'name' is formally deprecated and 'id' is to be used instead.

Comment: You can just put the `id` on the `div`. There is no real point in having a "orphaned" link.

Comment: The id doesn't have to be on an `<a>` element in HTML 4, although I can see how the spec is a little unclear on that.

Comment: @David Dorwards - thanks for the correction. @RoToRa - I see what you mean now. Answer updates (for the last time?)

Answer (score 8):

file.html will need an element with an `id="product"` attribute.  `name` is deprecated for `<a>` tags and shouldn't be used.

```
<div id="product"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please point me to the source that shows `name` is deprecated?

Comment: @Oded: [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10) in XHTML 1.0, and [the <a> element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element) in HTML 5 doesn't define the attribute.

Comment: yes thats what I have and it still just goes to the home div instead!

Answer (score 4):

**Don't use an anchor.** That is outdated. Just give the DIV the id `product`:

```
<div id="product">...</div>
```