# Open a link in new tab and go to a specific div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a link in a new tab and go to a specific div in that link. The link is:

http://paper.li/f-1333760510

and I want to go to the div `#paper-window` on clicking the link. Here is what I have tried:

1.

```
<a href="http://paper.li/f-1333760510#paper-window" target="_blank" />
```

2

```
<a href="#" onclick="load-link(); return false" />

function load-link() {
    var w = window.open("http://paper.li/f-1333760510");
    w.location.href = "http://paper.li/f-1333760510#paper-window";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The link looks ok... but you are misplacing the location.hash with the id of an element...

OLD:
your anchor markup is absolutely ok:

```
<a href="http://paper.li/f-1333760510#paper-window" target="_blank">open me</a>
<a name="paper-window"></a>
```

cause the `#something` part of the url is a jump point to a certain anchor on that page and not pointing to an id

UPDATE (regarding your comments, thanks to all of you :) )
the HTML5 spec for [Navigating to a fragment identifier](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#scroll-to-fragid) indeed says both will work... where the order is to first look for an id and afterwards for an anchor with attribute name (although deprecated in HTML5 for backward compatibility)

So this would mean opening http://www.example.com#foo would result in a search for:

```
// check for an element with an id matching "foo"
<div id="foo"></div>

// if no element was found check for an anchor with that name (also backward compatibility)
<a name="foo"></a>

// compare location.hash with "top"
// would jump to the top of the page if it matches
```

Comment: is there a way to go to a div element with id?...The link is external and cant change. BTW, when I place the link `http://paper.li/f-1333760510#paper-window` in the browser, it is jumping to the desired div, but only after loading the page for one time.

Comment: well this could be solved but only on the external page by reading the hash and working with it internally... I  just pasted that url and it did not jumped to the desired DIV... I think this happens since the browser remembers

Comment: hmm...yes..you are right...I just checked and realized that the jumping happens only for Fire-Fox and not for others like Chrome

Comment: hey, I think `name` is deperecated and `id` is the way to go..please see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309489/go-to-div-of-another-page-in-html)

Comment: thanks [rubyprince](http://stackoverflow.com/users/584440/rubyprince) there is still so much to be learned :) I updated the answer

Comment: just made a small test with Chrome and Firefox (stable releases)... working for me with id on div as well as with anchor and name and also `top` works

Comment: yes..but this happens only after loading the page once I think...so links like `a href="#paper-window"` works since it is the same page and the page is already loaded..but for external sites, where we load full url like `<a href="http://paper.li/f-1333760510#paper-window" />` is not going to the div..do you know how to specify the div after the external site is fully loaded?

Comment: ah I see... because not all content is already fetched but instead rendered on ajax? hmm, I see no possibility if you come from the outside... it just interferes with the asynchronous behavior of web pages... the spec just cover the possibilities on page rendering... everything lazy loaded is controlled by JS and most often done after dom:ready (therefore scrolling to a specific div needs to be done by the external page)