# to reach (ie. to unhide) a particular div using 'href' from other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, href

There is a pageA with 3 div(consider). also i'm having a link in another page. when users clicks the link they have to reach the 3rd div in pageA. How to do this?

> In my code all div are hidden except the one which is selected at that
>   time. so there is no need for scrolling.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sris/9nfwajf0/5/)

HTML:(PageA.html)

```
    <div id="mws-navigation">
        <ul id="link">
            <li class="" data-related="a" id="a1"><a href="#a"><i class="icon-book"></i>A</a></li>
            <li data-related="b" class="" id="b1"><a href="#b"><i class="icon-search"></i>B</a></li>
          <li data-related="c" class="" id="c1"><a href="#c"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>C</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>         
<!-- Main Container Start -->
<div id="mws-container" class="clearfix">
    <!-- Inner Container Start -->
        <div id="a" class="tab">
            aaaa
        </div>
        <div id="b" class="tab"> 
            bbbb
        </div>
        <div id="c" class="tab"> 
           cccc
        </div>
</div>
```

page B.html:

```
<a href="PageA.html#c">vvv</a>// this link will be in other page(to reach C)
```

// what i have to give in `herf=""` to reach that particular div

JQuery:

```
$(function()
    {

            $('#link li').removeClass('actif');
            $(this).find('li').addClass('actif');
            $('.tab').hide();
            $('#a').show();
            document.getElementById('a1').className='active';
            $('#link li').click(function(e){
            $('#link li').removeClass('actif');
            $(this).find('li').addClass('actif');
            $('.tab').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).attr('data-related')).show();
            e.preventDefault();
});
    });
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: i guess you could use html anchor or detect the position of the div and then scroll your screen to the correct position

Comment: @MarceloBezerra Not scrolling i need. When i click a div the particular div only be visible all other are hidden. So, from other page if i click a link (using `href`) it should only show the particular div what i requested, all others should be hidden. for ex, `<a href='PageA.html#c'>` it should show only the div `c` all others should be hidden.

Comment: this may help you out [possibly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3309520/2749470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think you're saying you want to show and focus on a particular element based on what a user has clicked on coming from another page.

On pageB add a parameter to your querystring in your hrefs like so:

```
<a href="PageA.html?showdiv=c">vvv</a>
```

If you have server side access - java, php or something then I would suggest using that to handle the query string and add a class to your div on pageA

```
<div id="c" class="tab showAndFocus"> cccc</div>

var myElementToShow = $(".showAndFocus");
myElementToShow.show();
myElementToShow.focus();
```

**OR**

However, if you only have jquery/javascript to do this (i.e. there is no server side to help you work with the query string) then you can get access to the query string parameters as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

```
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
       pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
       search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
       decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
       query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

       urlParams = {};
       while (match = search.exec(query))
           urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

Once you have the query string you can grab the div you want to show pretty easily...

```
var myElementToShow = $("#"+urlParams.showdiv);
myElementToShow.show();
myElementToShow.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read location.hash when pageA loads - in your jQuery load($) function